# How to validate your form using bootstrap in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have few textbox that validates when its empty, but they dont work well. Below is my logic from the model to view, what could i be missing? Currently these textbox dont seem to work and no error when i inspect from the browser. The application is on asp.net mvc using bootstrap.

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\w + ([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$")]
public string Email { get; set; }

// View
  <div class="row">
    <label for"Email">Email:</label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="input-group pull-right">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "email", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "example@example.com", required = "required" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, " ", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NB: even if i use @html.EditorBoxFor(m=>m.Email, new {Form...}) still nothing and no error.

Comment: It might help if you could narrow down "they dont work well"/"dont seem to work" into more focussed questions. If you narrow them enough, you might fix them yourself

Comment: @jalanb, my validation for email is not validating an error message like "This field is required". I did created this data notation on my Model, on view side i have put ValidationMessageFor. So that is why i am saying they not seem to work. Please assist me to make this work.